# How do I setup dual-head monitors with an Nvidia drivers and one monitor rotated?

Tags: nvidia, multi-monitor

I have an integrated ION GPU, which is supported by the proprietary drivers and I've never been able to get the open source drivers to work. I would like my left screen to be normal, but the right hand screen to be rotated. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It took me a while to work this out, so I wanted to share it with others.I will assume that the nvidia drivers and `nvidia-settings` are installed. (On Arch, run `sudo pacman -S nvidia nvidia-utils`.)

First, we need to generate a `xorg.conf` using `nvidia-settings`. From a GUI terminal, run `sudo nvidia-settings`.

1. Select "X Server Display Configuration" from the menu on the left.
2. On the right-hand side, change "Configuration" to "Separate X screen (requires X restart".
3. Check "Enable Xinerama".
4. Click "Save to X Configuration File"; `/etc/xorg.conf` will work, or you could add it as a new file to `/etc/xorg.conf.d` - e.g. `/etc/xorg.conf.d/10-monitors.conf`.

Now, we need to edit this file. Open it in your favourite editor as `root`. For example, run `gksu gedit /etc/xorg.conf` or `sudo vim /etc/xorg.conf`.

Find the correct `Section "Screen"`. I did this by finding the correct `Section "Monitor"` and then finding the corresponding `Section "Screen"`.

Find the line that looks like

```
Option "metamodes" "DFP-1: 1920x1080 +0+0"
```

and add `{ Rotation=Left }`, so it looks like

```
Option "metamodes" "DFP-1: 1920x1080 +0+0 { Rotation=Left }".
```

> *Note* `DFP-1` could be `DFP-0`, depending on which monitor you are rotating; the resolution is also likely to be different.

### Example

My `xorg.conf` reads as follows

```
Section "ServerLayout"
Identifier     "Layout0"
Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 28
Screen      1  "Screen1" 1280 0
InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
Option         "Xinerama" "1"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
Identifier     "Mouse0"
Driver         "mouse"
Option         "Protocol" "auto"
Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
Identifier     "Keyboard0"
Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "InputClass"
Identifier         "Keyboard Defaults"
MatchIsKeyboard    "yes"
Option         "XkbLayout" "gb"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
Identifier     "Monitor1"
VendorName     "Unknown"
ModelName      "HP w2228h"
HorizSync       24.0 - 83.0
VertRefresh     48.0 - 76.0
Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
Identifier     "Monitor0"
VendorName     "Unknown"
ModelName      "DELL 1703FP"
HorizSync       30.0 - 80.0
VertRefresh     56.0 - 76.0
Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
Identifier     "Device1"
Driver         "nvidia"
VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
BoardName      "ION"
BusID          "PCI:3:0:0"
Screen          1
EndSection

Section "Device"
Identifier     "Device0"
Driver         "nvidia"
VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
BoardName      "ION"
BusID          "PCI:3:0:0"
Screen          0
EndSection

Section "Screen"
Identifier     "Screen1"
Device         "Device1"
Monitor        "Monitor1"
DefaultDepth    24
Option         "TwinView" "On"
Option         "Stereo" "0"
Option         "metamodes" "DFP-1: 1920x1080 +0+0 { Rotation=Left }"
    SubSection     "Display"
    Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
Identifier     "Screen0"
Device         "Device0"
Monitor        "Monitor0"
DefaultDepth    24
Option         "TwinView" "On"
Option         "Stereo" "0"
Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-0"
Option         "metamodes" "DFP-0: 1280x1024 +0+0"
    SubSection     "Display"
    Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Extensions"
Option         "Composite" "Disable"
EndSection
```

#### References

1. [Linux Dual Monitor Setup: Nvidia & Xinerama Guide: Rotating just one monitor](http://zuttobenkyou.wordpress.com/2009/10/04/linux-nvidia-xinerama-guide-rotating-just-one-monitor-in-a-dual-head-setup/)

Answer (score 1):

It seems the most recent version of the closed source NVIDIA drivers supports randr (see http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTA5NTY). Just use the most recent driver and a RandR front-end of your choice. For example arandr will allow you to move monitors around and alter their orientation.